# how to add to fields in on field?

Tags: python, odoo

In `folio_num` field I wanted to get two value combined i.e. `'assetmodelid_add' + 'place'`. In my case I have done function on change method but their I am getting index not string value. this is complete code i have posted here  it has asset.asset and agile.poertfilio1 .py file. please go through it and tell me proper code .i think no need to add .xml file .

```
        from openerp.osv import fields, osv


    class asset_asset(osv.osv):
        _inherit = "asset.asset"
        #_name = "asset_asset"
        _rec_name= "folio_num"
        _columns = {
            'name': fields.char('Asset Name', size=64),
            'place': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Location'),
            'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
                'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
            'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',domain="[('area_id', '=', area_id)]",),
            'folio_num' : fields.char('Folio No',),
            'asse_line':fields.one2many('asset.line','emp_id','Name Plate'),
            'asse_line2':fields.one2many('asset.part','emp_id1','Parts'),
                   # 'assed_modelid':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model ID',select=True, required=True),
            'quantity': fields.char('Quantity',size=64),
            'uom': fields.char('Uinit of Measure',size=64),
            'model_no' : fields.char('Model', size=64),

            #'asset_id':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset ID'),

        }


        '''def get_asset_parts1(self, cr, uid, ids, assetmodelid_add,model_no, context=None):
            val = {}

            res = []

            if model_no:
                val['model_no'] = model_name


            return {'value': val}'''

        def onchange_first_last(self, cr, uid, ids, place, assetmodelid_add, context=None):
                v = {}
                asset_val=''
                place_val=''
                place_obj=self.pool.get('asset.parentlocation')
            asset_obj=self.pool.get('agile.portfolio1')

            if assetmodelid_add:
                    asset_val = asset_obj.browse(cr, uid, assetmodelid_add, context=None).name
            if place:
                    place_val = place_obj.browse(cr, uid, place, context=None).name

                v['folio_num'] = asset_val + place_val
                return {'value': v}

        def get_asset_parts(self, cr, uid, ids, assetmodelid_add,context=None):
            val = {}
            #
            res = []
            res2 = []
            res3 = []


            if assetmodelid_add:
                for asset in self.pool.get('agile.portfolio1').browse(cr,uid,assetmodelid_add,context=context):
                    for ass in asset.asspart_id1:
                        val = {
                            'pname_id' : ass.asspart_name,
                            'vsurname' : ass.assvalue_code,

                            }

                        res.append(val)
                    for ass in asset.strat_id1:
                        val = {
                            'part_name' : ass.start_name,
                            'part_code' : ass.strat_code,
                            'part_quty' : ass.strat_quty,
                            'part_uom' : ass.strat_uom,
                            }
                        res2.append(val)

                val['model_no'] = asset.model_name  


                val.update({'asse_line':res, 'asse_line2':res2,'model_no':asset.model_name })


            return {'value': val}



    asset_asset()

    class asset_attach(osv.osv):
        _inherit = "asset.asset"
        _columns = {
            #'rp_resume1' : fields.Binary(string='Resume'),
            #'rp_resume1_name' : fields.Char(string='File name')
            #'rp_more1_docs' : fields.many2many('ir.attachment', 'room_partner_attachment_rel', 'room_partner_id', 'attachment_id', 'More Documents'),
            'attachments': fields.many2many('ir.attachment', 'partner_id',string="Attachments"),

            #'nameee':fields.many2one('ir.attachment','Attachments'),
        }
    asset_attach()

    class asset_model_id(osv.osv):
        _inherit = "asset.asset"
        _columns = {

            'assetcat_id' : fields.char('Asset Catg',)
        }
    asset_model_id()

    class pname_line(osv.osv):
        _name='pname.line'
        _columns = {

            'name':fields.char('Name'),
        }

    pname_line()



    class asset_line(osv.osv):
        _name="asset.line"
        APPOINTMENT_SELECTION=[
            ('0','Regular'),
            ('1','Aditional'),
            ('2','Deputation'),

        ]
        _columns = {
            'pname_id':fields.char('Pname'),
            'vsurname':fields.char('Value'),

            'emp_id': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'vendor_id'),
        }

    asset_line()

    class pname_part(osv.osv):
        _name='pname.part'
        _rec_name = 'namee'
        _columns = {

            'namee':fields.char('Name'),
        }

    pname_line()

    class asset_part(osv.osv):
        _name="asset.part"
        #_rec_name = 'part_name'
        APPOINTMENT_SELECTION=[
            ('0','Regular'),
            ('1','Aditional'),
            ('2','Deputation'),

        ]
        _columns = {
            'part_name':fields.char('Name'),
            'part_code':fields.char('Code'),
            'part_quty':fields.char('Quantity'),
            'part_uom':fields.char('UoM'),
            'emp_id1': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'vendor_id'),
        }

    asset_part()


    class asset_parentlocation(osv.osv):
        _name="asset.parentlocation"
        _rec_name="parent_location"
        _columns = {
            'location_name' : fields.char('Asset Location', required=True),
            'parent_location' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Parent Location'),}

        def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            if context is None:
                context = {}
            if not ids:
                return []
            reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['location_name','parent_location'], context=context)
            res = []
            for record in reads:
                name = record['location_name']
                if record['parent_location']:
                    name = record['parent_location'][1]+' / '+name
                res.append((record['id'], name))
            return res


agile.portfolio1 .py file here

class asset_catg(osv.Model): 
    _name="asset.catg" 
    _rec_name='name1'
    _description="Define Asset Catgs" 
    _columns={ 'name1':fields.char('Asset Catg Names',size=64,required=True),}
asset_catg()

class asset_name(osv.Model): 
    _name="asset.name" 
    _rec_name='name'
    _description="Define asset name" 
    _columns={ 'name':fields.char('Asset Name',size=64,required=True),
        'material_code' : fields.char('Material Code',),
        #'area_type': fields.selection(area_type_lov,'Area Type',required=True), 
        'asset_catg_id':fields.many2one('asset.catg','Asset Catg Name',size=64,required=True),
}

asset_name()

class asset_config_super(osv.Model): 

    _name = "asset.config.super" 

    _description = "Assigning to substation"
    _columns = { 
         'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection', select=True, required=True),
        'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
    }

asset_config_super()

#Asset Creation 

class agile_portfolio1(osv.Model):
    _name = "agile.portfolio1"
    _rec_name = 'asset_id_add'
    _columns = {
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
            'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name','Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]",),  
        'material_code' : fields.char('Material Code'),
        'strat_id1' : fields.one2many('portfolio1.grid','strat_id','BoM',),
        'asspart_id1' :fields.one2many('asset1.grid','asspart_id','Specification',),
        'asset_id_add' : fields.char('Asset Model Code',),
        'make_name' : fields.char('Make',),
        'model_name': fields.char('Model',),

        #'asset_categ': fields.many2one('asset.cat','Asset Catg',select=True,required=True,ondelete="restrict"),
    }
    def get_meet_dets(self, cr, uid, ids, area_id, context=None):
        val = {}
        if area_id:
            for det in self.pool.get('asset.name').browse(cr,uid,area_id,context=context):
                    val = {
                        'material_code' : det.material_code,
                        }
        return {'value': val}

    def onchange_first_last(self, cr, uid, ids, make_name, model_name, context=None):
        v = {}
        #'area_ref':fields.related('area_ref','area_id',readonly=True,type='char',relation='agile.portfolio1',string='Area'),
        if make_name and model_name:
            v['asset_id_add'] = make_name + model_name
        return {'value': v}


agile_portfolio1()

class portfolio1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'portfolio1.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'start_name' : fields.char('Part'),
                'strat_code' : fields.char('Code'),
                'strat_quty' : fields.char('Quantity '),
                'strat_uom' : fields.char('UoM'),
                'strat_id': fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Strat Id'),
            }

portfolio1_grid()

class asset1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'asset1.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'asspart_name' : fields.char('Part'),
                'assvalue_code' : fields.char('Value'),

                'asspart_id': fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Specifications'),
            }

asset1_grid()
#Inspection Class


class asset1_inspection(osv.Model):
    _name = "asset1.inspection"

    MAINTENANCE_SELECTION=[
        ('0','Daily'),
        ('1','Weekly'),
        ('2','Fortnight'),
        ('3','Bi-Monthly'),
        ('4','Quarterly'),
        ('5','Half-Yearly'),
        ('6','Yearly'),
        ('7','Bi-Yearly'),

    ]
    MAINTENANCE_TYPE=[
        ('0', 'Corrective'),
        ('1', 'Preventive'),
        ('2', 'Predictive'),

    ]
    SHOUTDOWN_SELECTION=[
        ('0','YES'),
        ('1','NO'),

    ]
    _columns = {
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
            'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True), 
        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',domain="[('area_id', '=', area_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'inspection_name':fields.char('Inspection Type',),
        'freq_sel':fields.selection(MAINTENANCE_SELECTION,'Frequency'),

        'shut_down':fields.selection(SHOUTDOWN_SELECTION,'Shout Down'),
        'main_type':fields.selection(MAINTENANCE_TYPE,'Maintenance Type',),
        'insp_id1' : fields.one2many('inspec1.grid','insp_id','BoM',),
        'ainsp_id1' : fields.one2many('assetinspec1.grid','ainsp_id','Asset Maintenance',),
        #'asset_type': fields.many2one('asset.cat','Asset Categ'),
        #'asset_part_id': fields.many2one('ainspcat_name','Asset Cat',)

    }

asset1_inspection()

class inspec1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'inspec1.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'insp_name' : fields.char('Part'),
                'insp_code' : fields.char('Code'),
                'insp_quty' : fields.char('Quantity '),
                'insp_uom' : fields.char('UoM'),
                'insp_id': fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Insp Id'),
            }

inspec1_grid()

class assetinspec1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'assetinspec1.grid'
    _columns = { 
                'ainsp_name' : fields.many2one('assetcat1.grid','Asset Name',),
                'ainsp_id': fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','aInsp Id'),
            }

assetinspec1_grid()


class asset1_cat(osv.Model):
    _name = "asset1.cat"
    #_rec_name="asset_catname"

    _columns = {
        'asset_catname':fields.char('Asset Type',),
        'assetcat_id':fields.one2many('assetcat1.grid','ainspcat_id','Asset Name',)

    }

asset1_cat()

class assetcat1_grid(osv.Model):
    _name = 'assetcat1.grid'
    #_rec_name='ainspcat_name'
    _columns = { 
                'ainspcat_name' : fields.char('Asset Names'),
                'ainspcat_id': fields.many2one('asset1.cat','AssetCat ID'),
            }


assetcat1_grid()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hear many2one fields always have return the id not the value at that we need to browse the record from the that field to that particular object and use that existing field name as well**

you should follow some thing like this.

```
def onchange_first_last(self, cr, uid, ids, place, assetmodelid_add, context=None):
    v = {}
    assetmodelid_val=''
    place_val=''
    place_obj=self.pool.get('asset.parentlocation')
    assetmodelid_obj=self.pool.get('agile.portfolio1')

    if assetmodelid_add:
        assetmodelid_val = assetmodelid_obj.browse(cr, uid, assetmodelid_add, context=None).name
    if place:
        place_val = place_obj.browse(cr, uid, place, context=None).name

    v['folio_num'] = assetmodelid_val + place_val
    return {'value': v}
```

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Comment: it meas that your object have not in name field

Comment: so wt i need to do now

Comment: just make a new fields in your both of the object as name and  fill the name and then after you can do the onchange action

Comment: what not getting you must have to add the(name) fields of that particular object and then  do your job.

Comment: where bro i have object with differnt names i am not getting what you are tellin g let it be i will try myself. if i know i would not ask you thanks

Comment: place_obj=self.pool.get('asset.parentlocation')
  assetmodelid_obj=self.pool.get('agile.portfolio1')
add your fields in above two object and your field name as "name"

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
def onchange_first_last(self, cr, uid, ids, place, assetmodelid_add, context=None):
    v = {}
    asset_val=''
    place_val=''
    place_obj=self.pool.get('asset.parentlocation')
    asset_obj=self.pool.get('agile.portfolio1')

    if assetmodelid_add:
        asset_val = asset_obj.browse(cr, uid, assetmodelid_add, context=None).asset_id_add
    if place:
        place_val = place_obj.browse(cr, uid, place, context=None).name

    v['folio_num'] = asset_val + place_val
    return {'value': v}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'agile.portfolio1' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Can you please show me agile.portfolio1 model structure ?

Comment: class agile_portfolio1(osv.Model):
_name = "agile.portfolio1" _rec_name = 'asset_id_add'
_columns = {'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True), 'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name','Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]",),  'material_code' : fields.char('Material Code'),'strat_id1' : fields.one2many('portfolio1.grid','strat_id','BoM',)

Comment: ,'asspart_id1' :fields.one2many('asset1.grid','asspart_id','Specification',),'asset_id_add' : fields.char('Asset Model Code',), 'make_name' : fields.char('Make',), 'model_name': fields.char('Model',),}

Comment: had adde agile.portfolio1 code in comment and code section too

Comment: See I have changed answer.